# AutoSizable Swift 2

Tags: swift, swift2, autosize

This is a part of GameScene.swift.

I want to make `Background` and `Lives` auto sizable. This is the code that works only for iPad. I want that it can work on iPhone and I don't know how to do, because of the function `createLives`.

```
import SpriteKit
import AVFoundation

class GameScene: SKScene {

    var scoreLabel: SKLabelNode!
    var score: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            scoreLabel.text = "Score: \(score)"
        }
    }

    var livesImages = [SKSpriteNode]()
    var lives = 3

    var activeSliceBG: SKShapeNode!
    var activeSliceFG: SKShapeNode!

    var activeSlicePoints = [CGPoint]()

    var swooshSoundActive = false

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"sliceBackground")
        background.position = CGPoint(x: 512, y: 384)
        background.blendMode = .Replace
        background.zPosition = -10
        addChild(background)

        physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: -6)
        physicsWorld.speed = 0.85

        createScore()
        createLives()
        createSlices()
    }

    func createScore(){
        scoreLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Chalkduster")
        scoreLabel.text = "Score: 0"
        scoreLabel.horizontalAlignmentMode = .Left
        scoreLabel.fontSize = 48
        addChild(scoreLabel)
    }

    func createLives() {
        for i in 0 ..< 3 {
            let spriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "sliceLife")
            spriteNode.position = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(834 + (i * 70)), y: 720)
            addChild(spriteNode)
            livesImages.append(spriteNode)

        }

    }
```

Comment: According to your explanation, you have a problem with `createLives` function. Please, describe the actual problem.

Comment: the problem is that if I run my app on iPad the size work perfectly but if I run it on iPhone the size is the same that the iPad so it doesn't  shown on screen

Comment: Is it a size problem or a position problem?

Comment: Both, because I want to put lives near the upper right corner